# Batch in PHP system command

Tags: php, ubuntu, batch-file, jobs

This is on an Ubuntu system. When a user submits a job to our website, I want to run it as a batch job. Cmd.sh is a shell script. When run manually in terminal, the script executes fine, but for some reason won't run as a batch job. The current PHP is:

```
system("echo /var/www/dbCAN/data/blast/$jobid/cmd.sh | batch");
```

It doesn't print an error or crash, it simply doesn't submit the job. Furthermore, if I change this code to just remove the "| batch", the file executes normally. The reason I don't want to execute it directly is it's an intensive process that can take some time, and we typically email the user when their job is complete (and not run multiple jobs at once). Anyone have any ideas why this isn't working? I know the path is correct but I'm not sure about batch usage. Help is appreciated :)

Comment: Check the files `/etc/at.allow` and `/etc/at.deny` to see if the web user is allowed to use `at` and `batch`.

Comment: ^ at.deny did have www-data in it, which was part of the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man batch`:

> For  both  **at**  and  **batch**, commands are read from standard input or
>   the file specified with the **-f** option and executed.

<s>So maybe try `batch -f /var/www/dbCAN/data/blast/$jobid/cmd.sh`?</s>

Apparently, `batch` no longer supports arguments (I got `batch accepts no parameters` when I tried to run it with the `-f` argument). The following worked equivalently for me (obviously using a different file path):

```
at -q b -m now -f /var/www/dbCAN/data/blast/$jobid/cmd.sh
```

Reference: [#419547 - at: batch no longer accepts parameters](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=419547).

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that and the behavior didn't change, it's still not added ad a batch job (or executed).

Comment: Do you just want to run it in the background? If so, would something like `bash /var/www/dbCAN/data/blast/$jobid/cmd.sh &` work?.

Comment: Actually, you should probably disregard my previous suggestion. It doesn't seem like a very good idea to let users generate background jobs.

Comment: Your updated answer didn't work either. I tried running your command directly in terminal and nothing happened.

Comment: What is in the `$jobid` variable in your PHP script?

Comment: $jobid is a timestamp to differentiate jobs. They all have unique folders with data and the cmd.sh to be executed.

Comment: Ah ha! Your command worked after I restarted my machine to allow the changes to at.deny to take effect. Thank you!